# How do I configure RDP host to allow only SSL connection in Windows 10 PRO?

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, ssl

Despite having set in gpedit.msc,
Computer Configuration, Administrative Templates, Windows Components, RD Services, RD Session Host, Security:-

- Require use of specified security layer... set to SSL

I am still able to connect to RDP via IP address. I only want to allow RDP connection using domain name with a valid SSL connection.

Can anyone help to point out what did I miss out actually?

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Alvin L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am still able to connect to RDP via IP address. I only want to allow RDP connection using domain name with a valid SSL connection.

The first thing you missed is that "SSL" and "valid certificate" are two completely separate things. An SSL connection that fails certificate validation *is still an SSL connection.* It doesn't revert to the legacy RDP encryption layer.

(In fact, even without your GPO, hosts which require NLA will *always* use the TLS security layer, as NLA's CredSSP integrates TLS by design – the legacy RDP layer isn't even a possibility anymore. The GPO that you found is an old pre-NLA setting dating back to Server 2003.)

The second thing is that the server (i.e. the session host) has no way to enforce what validation the client must do. If the client gets a certificate error, it can just decide to proceed anyway, without telling the server about that.

So if you want valid certificates to be used, what you're looking for is a *client* setting, to be deployed via GPO on workstations – it cannot be enforced on the server.

---

However, in Active Directory environments, what you *could* enforce server-side is *reject NTLM authentication* and require Kerberos exclusively. Doing so will also make it mandatory to use the server's domain name instead of IP address (as Kerberos must find a matching SPN).

But it also has a particular advantage for RDP because NLA's CredSSP integrates TLS handshake validation with Kerberos ticket exchange (i.e. "channel binding"), so even if the certificate isn't verified in the traditional way, CredSSP will be able to detect MITM attacks regardless.

(Kerberos can be used even from non-member clients; to do so, enter the username in UPN format when logging in – i.e. connect as `user@domain.tld` instead of `domain\user`.)

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. I misinterpreted that SSL will only be enabled with a valid certification.